# how to take the time from the timer and use those values to adjust the visibility in vb

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub alertTimer()
    If (numXb > 3.7 And numXb < 2.7) Then
        TimerAlert.Start()

        If (t > 50) Then
            alertS.Visible = True
        ElseIf (t <= 50) Then
            alertS.Visible = False
        Else
            alertS.Visible = False

        End If
    End If
```

so im trying to have and image to flash on and off. but i don't really know how. im trying to take the time from the timer and use those values to adjust the visibility. yes, i am new to vb so please dont be harsh.